# ¿Como Ordenar Alfabeticamente un dataTable?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, datatables, eloquent

Estoy trabajando con php y el framework laravel con la librería de dataTables la cual me ha funcionado perfecto pero tengo un problema deseo ordenar el data table de una manera alfabética según el nombre de usuario pero el problema es que no ordena he intentado con las opciones de la librería como:

```
  $('#requirements-table').dataTable({
       aaSorting: [[1, "desc"]]
    });
```

Entre otras más y de igual manera he intentado haciéndolo desde eloquent con el order by el cual tampoco ha funcionado

```
 $user = User::select('users.id', 'users.name')
                        ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', 'users.id')
                        ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', 'roles.id')
                        ->whereNotIn('roles.name', ['admin', 'client'])
                        ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
                        ->get();
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

> A partir de este lugar ingreso más imágenes y código

Código Jquery para generar el dataTable en la vista blade

```
function loadTable(){
    var id = $("#invoice_id").val();
    var url = "{{ route('admin.invoices.ordersData',[":id"]) }}";
    var url = url.replace(':id',id);

table = $('#order-table').dataTable({
        responsive: true,
        destroy: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: url,
        "ordering":true,
        "order": [[ 2, 'asc']],
        language: {
            "url": "<?php echo __("app.datatable") ?>"
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
            $("body").tooltip({
                selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
            });
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            { data: 'sign_sheet', name: 'sign_sheet'},
            { data: 'order_sheet', name: 'order_sheet'},
        ],
    });
}
```

En el controlador en PHP

```
public function invoiceData($id){
    $orders = Order::select('*')->where('invoice','=',$id)->get();

    // var_export($orders);

    $requirements = Requirement::select('*')->whereIn('order_id',$orders)->get();

    // var_export($requirements);

    return DataTables::of($requirements)

    ->addColumn(
        'employee',
        function($row){
            $user = User::findOrFail($row->user_id);
            return $user->name;
        }
    )

->rawColumns('employee'])
->make(true);
```

Aquí la tabla generada, omito algunos datos no necesarios debido a la extensión del metodo.

[image: Tabla]

De está manera la primer persona en la tabla debería de ser Alejandra

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo la documentación de la página oficial. (https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)

He revisado y funciona correctamente.

Reemplaza tu código

```
aaSorting: [[1, "desc"]]
```

Por este

```
"order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]]
```

PD: Recuerda también que debes tener habilitado el ordering
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

```
"ordering": false
```

Tu código quedaría así

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ordering": true,
  "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]]
} );
```

Intentalo.

Comment: He intentado con el código como me dices pero sigo sin obtener el resultado en el orden que deseo, te dejo más ejemplos con otra tabla la cual quiero ordenar por el nombre del empleado